# How to organize requests for users in REST API?

Tags: api, rest

I have self-written API where urls are organized like:

```
GET /api/products
PUT /api/products/1
```

So there are controllers (ProductController.php, for example) and these controllers have four methods: get, post, put and delete.

1. Is this a right way to organize rest api?
2. If so, how to organize registration/authorization? Because both actions use POST method

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. API's URL structure seems fine. What exactly is your question about user endpoints?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' If I have four methods in my controller, which of them I have to use for auth and which for registration? I use simple JWT token for auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. I would recommend looking at how big companies are doing this kind of work. See how [Github](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues) is structuring their API
2. Relies on what kind of authentication/authorization you want to use. Most companies choose Oauth with JWT, you could also use session-based authentication. For me, it's not clear what you exactly want to do. Maybe you can elaborate on that.

Comment: If I have four methods in my controller, which of them I have to use for auth and which for registration? I use simple JWT token for auth

Comment: I would recommend using `POST` for doing the login and refresh token(s). See https://jwt.io for a list of libraries which already did some things of your implementation

Comment: but registration is also using POST method and eventually I have identical urls and methods for different actions - what is not right
`POST /api/users - for auth` and `POST /api/users - for registration`

Comment: Huh. I would recommend using a specific endpoint like `api/token` for doing all the token related things. And user management on the `api/users` endpoint. In this way, you have great separation of concerns.

Comment: Fantastic, it looks like I have to get rest because that's so easy :) Thank you